# Is it possible to tag a SSH key pair in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, tags, key-pair

[DescribeKeypairs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeKeyPairs.html) says that KeyPair can have tags, however it’s not possible to filter keys by tag or tag_key. Plus key pairs don’t have specific type ID, like `i-*`, `vol-*` and etc so tagging with CreateTags is also not possible. Creation via web not possible too. 
All this seems very confusing because there is no way to create tag but it can be tagged

Is there a way to tag key pairs?

Comment: Most of the "newer" services have `add-tags-to-resource` API, that accepts resource ARN such as `arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123456789012:key-pair/my-keyname`, but EC2 API seems to be an exception here. I would guess just because it's one of the very first/old things at AWS.

Comment: Somebody updated docs for KeyPairInfo this weekend. Now its all clear. Thanks silent AWS employee

Answer (score 2, accepted):

uhm...I haven't personally tried but using `describe-key-pairs` in the AWS CLI should give you the key id.

However the only way I found to tag the key id is by using AWS CLI to generate it and have a look at the output.

If you use a simple command:

```
aws ec2 create-key-pair --key-name my-test-key --profile my-profile
```

Then the output has the key id.

```
{
    "KeyFingerprint": "6d:5c:e0:19:de:.........",
    "KeyMaterial": "......",
    "KeyName": "my-test-key",
    "KeyPairId": "key-0ab4ff01abc9999e"
}
```

Then you can tag the resource by using `create-tags` that you already know.

Answer (score 0):

### **1. Ids**

As of **aws-cli version 2.2.11** for Linux, I find keys have ***KeyPairIds*** ...the **resource ids**.

### **2. On Tagging Keys**

Yes you can using **ec2 create-tags**. Using **create-key-pair** is quite problematic.

`aws ec2 create-tags help` is the reference for the commands below.

General command & arguments ...

```
aws ec2 create-tags \
 --resources "string" "string" --tags Key=string,Value=string ...
```

### **Example.**

First describe my keys to get **resource ids**...The Key Pair Ids.

```
aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --profile-name adrianteri-devops
```

**output**

```
{
    "KeyPairs": [
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-044180521638ac88d",
            "KeyFingerprint": "69:b4:71:46:65:40:37:59:7c:8c:5f:fa:c6:46:5a:e4:12:e0:46:54",
            "KeyName": "adrianteri-devops",
            "Tags": []
        },
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-0c010638921030fdc",
            "KeyFingerprint": "21:6b:f8:05:bc:96:13:8d:ba:75:41:bb:5b:43:15:f7:9c:b0:a3:a4",
            "KeyName": "ansible-devops",
            "Tags": []
        }
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-0d047bbc242c7e0a2",
            "KeyFingerprint": "69:2d:6f:6f:af:cf:45:d3:a9:d5:e7:63:b3:54:8b:85:32:67:9e:a0",
            "KeyName": "test-keypair",
            "Tags": []
        }

    ]
}
(END)
```

**Now create tags...**

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources key-044180521638ac88d key-0c010638921030fdc --tags Key=Project,Value=adrianteri-com Key=CreatedBy,Value=adrianteri --profile adrianteri-devops
```

Test Keypair has different tags.

```
aws ec2 create-tags --resources key-0d047bbc242c7e0a2 --tags Key=Project,Value=Test Key=CreatedBy,Value=TestBot Key=Billing,Value=QualityAssuarance --profile adrianteri-live-devops
```

**Result of describing my key pairs again:**

```
{
    "KeyPairs": [
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-044180521638ac88d",
            "KeyFingerprint": "69:b4:71:46:65:40:37:59:7c:8c:5f:fa:c6:46:5a:e4:12:e0:46:54",
            "KeyName": "adrianteri-devops-keypair",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Project",
                    "Value": "adrianteri-com"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "CreatedBy",
                    "Value": "adrianteri"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-0c010638921030fdc",
            "KeyFingerprint": "21:6b:f8:05:bc:96:13:8d:ba:75:41:bb:5b:43:15:f7:9c:b0:a3:a4",
            "KeyName": "ansible-devops-keypair",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Project",
                    "Value": "adrianteri-com"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "CreatedBy",
                    "Value": "adrianteri"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-0d047bbc242c7e0a2",
            "KeyFingerprint": "69:2d:6f:6f:af:cf:45:d3:a9:d5:e7:63:b3:54:8b:85:32:67:9e:a0",
            "KeyName": "test-keypair",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Project",
                    "Value": "Test"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "CreatedBy",
                    "Value": "TestBot"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Billing",
                    "Value": "QualityAssuarance"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
(END)
```

### **3. Filtering Keys by Tags**

Also possible using **--filters** `tag-key` and `tag :<key>`.

`tag-key`

```
aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --filters Name=tag-key,Values=Billing --profile adrianteri-devops
```

**output**

```
{
    "KeyPairs": [
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-0d047bbc242c7e0a2",
            "KeyFingerprint": "69:2d:6f:6f:af:cf:45:d3:a9:d5:e7:63:b3:54:8b:85:32:67:9e:a0",
            "KeyName": "test-keypair",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Project",
                    "Value": "Test"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "CreatedBy",
                    "Value": "TestBot"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "Billing",
                    "Value": "QualityAssurance"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
(END)
```

`tag :<key>`

```
aws ec2 describe-key-pairs --filters Name=tag:CreatedBy,Values=adrianteri -profile adrianteri-devops
```

**output**

```
{
    "KeyPairs": [
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-044180521638ac88d",
            "KeyFingerprint": "69:b4:71:46:65:40:37:59:7c:8c:5f:fa:c6:46:5a:e4:12:e0:46:54",
            "KeyName": "adrianteri-devops-keypair",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Project",
                    "Value": "adrianteri-com"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "CreatedBy",
                    "Value": "adrianteri"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "KeyPairId": "key-0c010638921030fdc",
            "KeyFingerprint": "21:6b:f8:05:bc:96:13:8d:ba:75:41:bb:5b:43:15:f7:9c:b0:a3:a4",
            "KeyName": "ansible-devops-keypair",
            "Tags": [
                {
                    "Key": "Project",
                    "Value": "adrianteri-com"
                },
                {
                    "Key": "CreatedBy",
                    "Value": "adrianteri"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
(END)
```